# android activity transparency

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

Is it possible to have your android activity run on top of the current running activity in a transparent mode so you can see through it the activity below it? If possible, can you have different levels of transparency?

Comment: When you say "current running activity" - even if the second activity is transparent, the first activity will stop "running" when the second starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a dialog theme or a translucent theme to your activity.  More info here: [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) under the "Apply a theme to an Activity or application" section.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

In Main.xml

android:background="#20FFFFFF"

```
#00FFFFFF -  Full Transparency
#10FFFFFF -  90% Transparency
#20FFFFFF -  80% Transparency
#30FFFFFF -  70% Transparency
#40FFFFFF -  60% Transparency
#50FFFFFF -  50% Transparency
#60FFFFFF -  40% Transparency
#70FFFFFF -  30% Transparency
#80FFFFFF -  20% Transparency
#90FFFFFF -  10% Transparency
#99FFFFFF -  01% Transparency
```

20 is transparency level and FFFFFF is color